# Component.destroy not available for components from difference namespaces

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a "manager" component , who is delivered in a managed package.

One of its role is to instanciate a "step component" , then when we click on next, we instanciate a new component and destroy the previous one so it doesn't remain in memory ( catching events etc ... whereas it has no use to be still alive )

With LockerService activated, method destroy is exposed only for components in the same namespace, but for components of other namespaces, it is not exposed, so it provokes a crash.

I avoided it by a try/catch but it's not good because the component remains instanciated ...

Please someone have a solution ?

Note: my "step" components can be with default namespace (c) but inheriting from a package component ( PK__TemplateComponent ), so i'm not sure than creating an aura:method on PK_TemplateComponent that will call component.destroy will work ...

[image: Other namespace component]

[image: Same namespace component]